# MaxListenersExceededWarning tls socket npm installation

Tags: npm, npm-install, tls1.2, eventemitter

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How to resolve this error?

how to resolve this error??
how to resolve this error??
how to resolve this error??how to resolve this error??

Comment: Hi, could you please reformat your question? for better readability.